# Kotlin superClass Kclass

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I have definiction of the function

```
abstract class AbstractDao<T>(private val dataStore: KotlinEntityDataStore<Persistable>): Dao<T> where T: Persistable
```

and I need to get `KClass` from type `T`. It is possible in Kotlin ?

Comment: Did you mean `dataStore: KotlinEntityDataStore<T>`? I don't understand why there is a generic type argument for `Persistable` then a explicit `Persistable` argument

Comment: KotlinEntityDataStore<Persistable> is only parameter of constructor. I need to get Kclass from T parameter :)

Comment: No, due to JVM type erasure unless you are able to reference a non-null instance of `T`, it is impossible to do solely from the class signature. An option around this is to make the constructor private and put an inline function (in companion object) with a reified `T` argument which returns an instance of `AbstractDao<T>`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). But you could provide a factory method with `reified type` that delegates to a constructor accepting the `KClass`. Here's a simplified example:

```
class WithReifiedType<T> constructor(val kc: KClass<*>) {
    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T> getInstance(): WithReifiedType<T> {
            println("Here's your KClass: ${T::class}")
            return WithReifiedType(T::class)
        }
    }
}

//called like this
WithReifiedType.getInstance<String>()
```

It's also acceptable to create a top-level function (as an alternative to companion-embedded factory) looking like a constructor on the caller site.

```
inline fun <reified T> WithReifiedType(): WithReifiedType<T> {
    println("Here's your KClass: ${T::class}")
    return WithReifiedType(T::class)
}

//called like this
WithReifiedType<String>()
```